# Getting mouse click in design time, but also let the control be selected at the same time

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I am creating a custom control that acts like the `TabControl`. I want the tab headers to be clickable in design time, just like the TabControl. Using the sample code I found on the Microsoft site, I wrote the following code. It works, but there is one problem.

As for the real `TabControl`, if you click a tab header when the TabControl has not been selected, the selected tab changes, AND the TabControl gets selected showing the resizing border which has a moving handle and a small button for "TabControl Tasks".

Doing the same thing with my code below only changes the selected tab header; it does not make my control be selected. I think I need to tell the Visual Studio Designer to select my control, somehow. But how?

```
public class MyDesigner : System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner
{
    private Adorner MyAdorner;
    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);

        MyAdorner = new Adorner();
        this.BehaviorService.Adorners.Add(MyAdorner);
        MyAdorner.Glyphs.Add(new MyGlyph(BehaviorService, (MyTabControl)Control));
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && MyAdorner != null)
        {
            BehaviorService b = BehaviorService;
            if (b != null)
            {
                b.Adorners.Remove(MyAdorner);
            }
        }
    }

    class MyGlyph : Glyph
    {
        MyTabControl TargetControl;
        BehaviorService behaviorSvc;

        public MyGlyph(BehaviorService behaviorSvc, MyTabControl targetControl)
            :base(new ClickingBehaviour())
        {
            this.behaviorSvc = behaviorSvc;
            this.TargetControl = targetControl;
        }

        private void OnMouseClick(MouseButtons button, Point adornerPoint)
        {
            var screenPoint = behaviorSvc.AdornerWindowPointToScreen(adornerPoint);
            var targetPoint = TargetControl.PointToClient(screenPoint);
            TargetControl.DesignTimeClick(button, targetPoint);
        }

        public override Rectangle Bounds
        {
            get
            {
                Point edge = behaviorSvc.ControlToAdornerWindow(TargetControl);
                Size size = TargetControl.Size;
                Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(edge, size);
                return bounds;
            }
        }

        public override Cursor GetHitTest(Point p)
        {
            Cursor handled = null;
            if (Bounds.Contains(p))
            {
                var screenPoint = behaviorSvc.AdornerWindowPointToScreen(p);
                var targetPoint = TargetControl.PointToClient(screenPoint);
                if(TargetControl.IsHeaderArea(targetPoint))
                    handled = Cursors.Default;
            }

            return handled;
        }

        public override void Paint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
        }

        class ClickingBehaviour : Behavior
        {
            public override bool OnMouseDown(Glyph g, MouseButtons button, Point mouseLoc)
            {
                MyGlyph myG = g as MyGlyph;
                myG.OnMouseClick(button, mouseLoc);
                return base.OnMouseDown(g, button, mouseLoc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to do it with the approach which uses an Adorner as above. So, I resorted to using Win32 message (I tried to avoid using Win32 for interoperability).

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0201 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0x0001)
    {
        var target = (Control as MyTabControl);
        if (true) //how to know if focused?
        {
            var lparam32 = m.LParam.ToInt32();
            int lowWord = lparam32 & 0xffff;
            int highWord = lparam32 >> 16;
            Point p = new Point(lowWord, highWord);
            if (target.IsHeaderArea(p))
            {
                target.DesignTimeClick(MouseButtons.Left, p);
            }
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

It works, but the only minor problem is that the tab index changes at the first click when the tab is not selected. Clicking a tab on a real `TabControl` when it is not selected does not change the tab but only selects the tab. But I guess I can live with this minor difference.